# How common is yod-coalescence in modern RP?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, received-pronunciation, yod-coalescence

I am an non native English speaker in where the some pronunciations taught have been obsolete in British English . Recently, I've got some time to do my research and discovered something called yod-coalescence.

Yod-coalescence sometimes occurs with clusters, like /dj/ and /tj/ which coalesce into /dʒ/ and /tʃ/ respectively.

For example, **during** would be pronounced as /dʒʊərɪŋ/ instead of /djʊərɪŋ/, and **Tuesday** would be pronounced as /tʃuːzdeɪ/ instead of /tjuːzdeɪ/.

How common is it in modern RP?

Comment: The difficulty is with "modern RP" - there isn't really a well-defined RP any longer. As far as the yod-coalescence is concerned, it is very common indeed in all but the most careful speech.

Comment: Everyone speaks like a barrow-boy these days; even younger royalty.

Comment: But I don't agree that RP is altogether dead.

Comment: One of my favourite jokes riffs on this tendency: "Why was Anne Boleyn found with Henry VIII's toothmarks all over her?" "Because he's Tudor."

Answer (score 1):

It is increasingly common.

As some commenters pointed out, it is not necessarily easy to find out what constitutes "modern RP", or whether such a thing exists, but as concerns the standard varietie(s) based on southern English speech used as a model for learners, yod coalescence at the beginning of stressed syllables traditionally pronounced with /tj, dj/ is now accepted as part of the standard, if not more common.

John Wells marked pronunciations with coalescence as "non-RP" in the 2000 edition of the *Longman Pronunciation Dictionary*, but he dropped it for the 2008 edition ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VlY1Z3SfoXY&t=5m)'s a video of him explaining it).

The 2011 edition of the *Cambridge English Pronouncing Dictionary* went so far as to give priority to pronunciation with /tʃ, dʒ/ over /tj, dj/, saying "it now seems /tʃuːn/ and /dʒuːn/ are more widely used and these pronunciations are given priority for most such words, with the /tj/ and /dj/ pronunciations as second choice" ([pp. xviii–xix](https://books.google.com/books?id=bfLXAAAAQBAJ&pg=PR18)).