# How to pronounce "stupid", "YouTube" and words like this?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

In dictionaries like Cambridge or Oxford it pronounced like "stjupid". But I hear how some people pronounce it like "stchupid". Is it different dialect or what's the reason?

Comment: You are hearing regional differences.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Oy vey! [ˈstjupɪd] vs [ˈstupɪd] is regional, but [ˈʃtupɪd] is a completely different shtick. See also *schmooze, schlep, schlock, schmaltz, shpiel* and plenty more besides.

Comment: It's very common to hear people pronounce "stupid" stupidly, usually for the sense of irony.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that with *stchupid* you mean to represent a pronunciation starting with something like [stʃ] in the International phonetic alphabet (the "s" sound of "say" followed by the "ch" sound of "chew").

In British English, words that dictionaries show as having syllable-initial consonant clusters /tj/ and /dj/ are often pronounced with phonetic affricates [tʃ] or [dʒ]. This has been discussed elsewhere on this site; see [Nardog's answer here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/537716/77227). Likewise, /stj/ can sound like [stʃ].

Answer (score 2):

In British-English that would be *"stew-pid"*; in American-English that would be "*stoo-pid"*